# Executing error_handler() during NN prediction

Tags: neural-network, error-handling

I am taking the [course: Sequences, Time Series and Prediction](https://www.coursera.org/learn/tensorflow-sequences-time-series-and-prediction/). In this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/https-deeplearning-ai/tensorflow-1-public/blob/main/C4/W2/ungraded_labs/C4_W2_Lab_2_single_layer_NN.ipynb) we train for the first time a single layer neural network, and I see at the bottom line: executing `error_handler()` which sounds like there is some problem, what is this error_handler() and is it really a problem?

[image]